# Accessing impact of deleting ibtmp1 file in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7, windows

There is a file called `ibtmp1` and it is consuming 138 GB. I understand, this stores uncompressed data. Do we really need these files or can we delete it? if deleting is fine, then could you please share the command or the process. Please note that I am using Windows system and MySQL Server version is 5.6

thank you.

Answer (score 4):

That file comes from MySQL 5.7, not 5.6. You can check by connecting to MySQL and running:

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
```

Shrinking `ibtmp1` would require shutting down MySQL. You cannot just the delete the file because there will be a open file handle on that file coming from `mysqld.exe`.

First, log into MySQL and run:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0;
```

Next, shutdown MySQL, delet the file and start mysql back up:

```
C:\> net stop mysql
C:\> del ibtmp1
C:\> net start mysql
```

If your `ibtmp1` grew that much, then you have been running some bad queries that create large temp tables.

Comment: Can't we restrict the ibtmp1 file size, instead of restarting all the time whenever size grows .

Comment: @naveen_sfx You should probably store the ibtmp1 file on a larger volume (http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/136632/877)

Comment: I agree with providing higher volume, want to restrict the ibtmp1 size. ex: some 10GB , so it should not grow beyond the 10G.  Because my dwh is on mysql. currently i cant restrict dev team to restrict writing bad queries which are expected on this environment.  So due to this  ibtmp1 is increased upto 2T.  (95% data on tokudb , remaining on innodb. ) 5% of innodb made 2T ibtmp1 file

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict size using:

```
**innodb_temp_data_file_path=ibtmp1:12M:autoextend:max:10G**
```